# Dynamic Apex:Repeat size (adding rows)

Tags: apex, repeat, count

I've tried to make a button that would add another row to apex:repeat that has couple apex:inputField fields in it, but with no success (i'm getting "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error)

I've created a List of objects in controller and with my method I'm adding new elements to it (which should increase row count on page), I was thinking about rerender, but even then I shouldn't be getting null reference error.

I'm pretty sure that this should be possible and I'm missing something simple.

Here's code sample:

```
<apex:page controller="CostInvoiceController" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS220,'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}"/>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en"/>
    <div class="clorce" name="Button List">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-center slds-text-align--center">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded slds-m-top--medium slds-m-bottom--medium">
                <apex:form >
                <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cost Name">Cost Name</div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                    <apex:repeat value="{!costInvoices}" var="cost" id="theRepeat">

                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" data-label="Cost Name">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Date"><apex:inputField value="{!cost.Data_platnosci__c}" styleClass="slds-input"/>    </div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </apex:repeat>  
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                </table><br/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Dodaj line item" action="{!addInvoice}" styleclass="slds-button slds-button--brand"/> 
                </apex:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class CostInvoiceController {
    public List<Cost_Invoice__c> costInvoices {get; set;}

   public void addInvoice() 
   {
       Cost_Invoice__c NewCI = new Cost_Invoice__c(Data_wystawienia_faktury__c =date.today() ,Data_platnosci__c = date.today());
   costInvoices.add(NewCI);
   }

}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code? It'd be a lot easier if we could see your work so far.

Comment: It's nothing big, but here it is. (note that this is not finished so don't be bothered by method naming and such :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, whenever you have a variable, you need to initialize it. Since you failed to do so, you got the NullPointerException. To resolve this, you need to add a no-args [constructor](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_constructors.htm) in order to initialize the list:

```
public class CostInvoiceController {
    public List<Cost_Invoice__c> costInvoices {get; set;}
    public CostInvoiceController() {
        costInvoices = new List<Cost_Invoice__c>();
    }
    public void addInvoice() 
    {
        Cost_Invoice__c NewCI = new Cost_Invoice__c(Data_wystawienia_faktury__c =date.today() ,Data_platnosci__c = date.today());
        costInvoices.add(NewCI);
    }

}
```

Comment: I knew it was something small :D Thank a lot for help, this resolved my problem.